# freeswitch mod_xml_curl.c:468 Binding has no url

Tags: freeswitch

I am new to freeswitch and want to have a dynamic user directory. For this I want to use mod_xml_curl but when I load it I always get this error.

For information my freeswitch runs in a docker. I tried to run `make mod_xml_curl-install` and I get an error with make.

I don't know what to do

[image]

[image]

[image]